# Flutter ListView optimization

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Displaying large/infinitive list with scrolling offset in **Flutter** framework can be unacceptably slow (depending on the offset size).

This can be solved by specifying *itemExtend* when all items have the same size.

But it is not usually possible to know *itemExtend* in advance even when all list items have the same size because the height might depend on font size which depends on user phone accessibility settings.

> Is there any way to indicate to **Flutter** **ListView** that all list
>   items have the same size without knowing what exactly the size is?

If not is there any way to calculate list item widget size first (and then use it to set *itemExtend*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>I don't believe there is a way to automatically calculate the widget size first, however you can do manual calculations as much as you want.</s> You can use [`DefaultTextStyle.of(context)`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) to get the font size of the enclosing context and use a [LayoutBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get the maximum width of the list if that matters. You can then use those pieces of information to set the `itemExtent`.

However, you can get exactly what you want if you use a CustomScrollView and a [SliverPrototypeExtentList](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverPrototypeExtentList-class.html). You simply provide your prototype along with a SliverChildDelegate (probably [SliverChildBuilderDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverChildBuilderDelegate-class.html)) and it should figure out the rest.

And finally... I'm a little bit curious whether you'd share the part of your code where you actually instantiate the list (and what's shown within it). In my experience, **when you're in release mode** you can throw an awful lot of stuff at a ListView and still have it be smooth, so it's possible there's something else you're doing that's causing the slowdown. In debug mode it's very different of course.

Comment: I think that if even simple DetailTile is shown in ListView the performance can be very bad in release mode for large list. Consider ListView representing calendar starting at year 2000. To show "today" item  Flutter would have to calculate ~6400 widgets under 20 ms if itemExtent is not specified to make smooth user experience

Comment: Added info about SliverPrototypeExtentList - I think it's what you want.

Comment: SliverPrototypeExtentList solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can we see a working example of the solution please? 