# How can I optimize the display of X Texts of variable lenght widgets in flutter

Tags: optimization, flutter, dart

I have this list of widgets that are `Container` which contain a Title and A Body text the length of which is variable. For Example, I can have a text of two words and one of 30, so the number of rows can vary. I tried displaying them with a ListView.builder but when I display them, the performance drops to 20 frames/s, I tested it in the real world and the performance stays about the same. I tried looking online and found an answer ([Flutter ListView optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792215/flutter-listview-optimization)) which suggested using a CustomScrollView and a SliverPrototypeExtentList, so I looked on the docs and found that this widget builds all its children to be the size of a prototype widget, so I don't think that's what I'm looking forward to use. I tried it anyways but I couldn't manage to display anything and found no tutorials on how to use it online, this is the code I tried. (the application just freezes without anything happening):

```
CustomScrollView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    semanticChildCount: _actions.length,
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverPrototypeExtentList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              width: 200.0,
              height: 20 + 100 * Random().nextDouble(),
            );
          }),
          prototypeItem: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 200.0,
            height: 100.0,
          )),
    ],
  )
```

where _actions is a list of almost 100 elements.

Is there a better option than this or am I just using the widgets wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I might have missed something, but after researching a little bit more I found how to use the SliverChildBuilderDelegate stated in the answer I linked:

```
CustomScrollView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            GameAction action = _actions[index];
            return LeikunnActionCard(action: action);
          }, childCount: _actions.length),
        ),
      ]),
```

Basically a SliverList builds items lazily when they get displayed. So there are no performance issues.